# why does dashboard membership number not match list of members?

Tags: civimember

my membership dashboard shows 901 current members.

when i click the clickable '901'  I get a list of 902 members!

i cannot figure out why :/

what is the difference please between the query that generates the total membership number in the dashboard and the query that runs when you click on the number?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dashboard is programmed to show memberships that have a start date, whereas the search is not including that filter. If you are getting a different number in the search than in the dashboard, click on the Start date column to sort in descending order to find the record that is missing a start date - once you update that record, the numbers should be one and the same on the dashboard and on the search.

Hope this helps!

Editing to include screenshot regarding my last comment:

[image]

Comment: thank you:)  I've just checked and all memberships listed have start dates :(  is there any other difference between the dashboard and the search filters?

Comment: i think i have it.  the dashboard (i think?) shows members with a start date before the current date?  the search shows current members without a start date filter.

Comment: Hi again - by definition, if a membership has a future start date, then it wouldn't be considered current (hence if a membership doesn't have a start date, it wouldn't be included in the dashboard) - BUT, the real difference is that the search uses the "Current Member" setting that is defined in your membership status rules, so if your membership status rules include memberships with start dates in the future as current, that's why they are appearing on your search but not in the dashboard (see the screenshot included in my edited response for visual reference).